# Audio input/output splitter for MacBooks without changeable input/output jack?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones, microphone

From what I can understand, in the latest iterations of the MacBooks, what former was an input/output 3.5mm jack, now only can be used for input. However, it's possible to use certain headsets (for example the one that comes as standard with the iPhone) and get both audio in and out.

Shouldn't it be possible to build an audio input/output splitter for the mini jack? That is, a cord that splits up into an input and an output part, resulting in two female 3.5 connectors, to which you can connect your headphones and your mic? Is there even such a product out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are called 3.5mm 4 pin splitter, they separate a 4pin 3.5mm jack in 2 standard 3.5mm jack (1 for headphones, 1 for mic) as this one:

[Startech.com 3.5mm 4 Pin to 2x 3 Pin 3.5mm Headset Splitter Adapter - M/F](http://amzn.to/Ze4ns9)

you can read the comments, there are also some mac users that bought this splitter.

Comment: That's great. I'll definitely check it out! I wonder if it's possible to take this input into recording software, for example Adobe Audition or Reason.

Comment: Hmm...It seems like these things only are capable of supports mono in (that is, not stereo). Is that correct?

Comment: I didn't find specs about the 3.5mm jack used on macbooks (I think they are standards TRRS but capable of mic stereo) but if you are interested in audio recording maybe is better to think about an usb sound card.

Comment: Well, I want to find a way to hook up a Tascam DR-40 to my computer without loosing the stereo capability. This would only be used for voice over work so I'd probably be fine without a dedicated USB sound card.

Trying to find some more info about this port. I guess that the input supports mic level signals.

Comment: The linked adapter doesn't work with modern Apple devices (CTIA standard). DO. NOT. BUY.

Comment: @Urda do you have any more information about that (a 4 pin splitter not working with modern Apple devices)? I'm also wondering (since you seem to know about this topic) whether you can help me with this unanswered question about the headphone port on my Macbook Air: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267161/external-mic-not-working-anymore-on-macbook-air